# Printing Strings diagonaly instead of on the left

Tags: c, string, printing

I wanna print a huge array of strings, page by page so to say, but to skip the pages I didnt want to have to press enter. The only reasonable solution I found online was to use "stty raw".
That said, I ended up with this code

```
void printAux(char** Strings, int init, int fim){
  system("clear");
  for(int i = init; i < fim; i++){
    printf("%s\n", Strings[i]);
  }
}

void printStrings(char** Strings, int tam){

  int j = 0;
  int i = 0;
  char c;

  system("stty raw");
  printAux(Strings, 0, (tam >= 20 ? 20 : tam));
  while((c = getchar()) != 'q'){
    if(c == 'a'){
      i-= 20;
      i = (i < 0 ? 0 : i);
    }
    else if (c == 'd'){
      i += 20;
      i = (i > tam ? i - 20 : i);
    }
    printAux(Strings, i, (i + 20 >= tam ? tam : i + 20));
  }

  system("stty cooked");

}
```

It prints them just fine, but, it prints them like this

```
1
 2
  3
   4
    5
     6
      7
       8
        9
         10
           11
             12
               13
                 14
                   15
                     16
                       17
                         18
                           19
                             20
```

The lines starts printing at the row where the last one ended.
I'd like it to all be to the left of the screen.
Any help would be very appreciated

Comment: Maybe `printf("%s\r\n", ...);`?

Comment: Nice @pmg . Works perfect now.... Thanks

Comment: Great! Feel free to accept your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to replace

```
printf("%s\n", String[i]);
```

for

```
printf("%s\r\n", String[i]);
```